# NodeJS + CouchDB: Migrate from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, ionic-framework, https, couchdb

I have the following setup:

- a windows server which I login to through remote desktop;
- in this server I move the www folder of my ionic/node.js project;
- this server works as a web server through http on port 80;
- this website uses a couchdb database on port 5984.

Now, I am trying to migrate my whole system to https.

Just to try, I have made a SSL certificate which I signed myself (when everything works, I will buy a proper SSL certificate).
Now, with the certificate, I am able to access the website at

> https://www.mywebsite.it:3000/

But I have the following problems:

- my browser keeps detecting the website as unsafe, and I have to authorizing it before accessing. I think that's because the SSL is self-signed
- If I open Chrome developer tools, I get the following message:
  "Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
  I have to authorize it, in Chrome, through the following button

[image]

How to solve this? I would like, obviously, that users won't have to authorize so many things.

Comment: Did you [setup CouchDB for SSL](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#https-ssl-tls-options)? Also, to identify which request is still done via HTTP, check Network tab in chrome dev tools. Could also be loading an external image or script.

Comment: Well, I didn't setup CouchDB for SSL. That was the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I run servers on Ubuntu rather than Windows, but one way to solve this is to use [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/download.html) on your server as a reverse proxy. There are a number of tutorials to help you set up Nginx with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (free SSL certificates) so that HTTPS connections to your server go to Nginx on port 443 and then Nginx redirects the requests to port 80 for your existing web server.

If CouchDb should be accessed from the internet rather than just Node.js you can use Nginx to redirect incoming CouchDb requests from port 443 to port 5984 as well.

Of course you may also be able to set up whichever web server you are already using as a reverse proxy. But using Nginx is a well-trodden path with plenty of install and configuration help/advice on here and elsewhere.